# Video become interlaced of the Motion Menu (DVD) in Adobe Encore CS6

Tags: adobe

This problem only occur on DVD menu, video is progressive and with Text in the menu. in Blu-Ray disc, motion menu works perfect.

I tested created a simple menu with video as background (720 x 480 progressive 29.97 m2v). the dvd motion menu works fine, the video looks great in the menu.
but if i add the text in the same menu, the created DVD motion menu will be interlaced !

is this a bug ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem myself.

the problem is my VM (windows 8.1 running on Parallel, Macbook Pro 2013 late 15" Retina with intel iris pro 5200)
i copy the rendered motion menu video file to other pc there is no interlaced on the video !!

i am using K-Lite_Codec_Pack_1090_Standard in the VM.